# How to throw custom exception from resilience4j TimeLimitter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, vavr, resilience4j

I am using resilience4j's TimeLimiter to control timeout requests for a RestTemplate call. I am throwing a custom exception if the response.getBody() is null but, resilience4j's always throwing exception provided in getorElseThrow. how can I throw a custom exception here?

```
Try.ofCallable(methodWhichThrowsCustomException).getOrElseThrow(throwable -> {throw new ApplicationException(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
                    ErrorConstant.ERROR_CODE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, ErrorConstant.ERROR_MESSAGE_TIME_OUT);
        });
    }
```

Here i am trying throw the exception that the "methodWhichThrowsCustomException" throws, but i am not able to do that it only throws the exception the thrown here.

Comment: Show your work so far

Comment: Please update the question with the code. Not in the comments

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `resilience4j` but I'm pretty sure you are using `getOrElseThrow` wrong. The syntax you most likely want is this:

```
Try.ofCallable(methodWhichThrowsCustomException())
   .getOrElseThrow(throwable -> new ApplicationException(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, ErrorConstant.ERROR_CODE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, ErrorConstant.ERROR_MESSAGE_TIME_OUT));
```

Note that you don't need to `throw` inside `getOrElseThrow`, you only need to return the new exception to throw, Vavr will take care of throwing it.

Answer (score 0):

### Vavr's `Try.of().getOrElseThrow()`

See the blog [Vavr One Log 03 - A Safe Try](https://blog.vavr.io/vavr-one-log-03/):

> T getOrElseThrow(Supplier)

`getOrElseThrow` expects an *exception-supplier* as argument. This may be a lambda, method-reference, or any functional.
Its purpose is to map the thrown exception to your instance of a custom Exception. For example:

```java
Try.ofCallable(methodWhichThrowsCustomException)
    .getOrElseThrow(throwable -> new CustomerException(
        HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT,
        ErrorConstant.ERROR_CODE_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 
        ErrorConstant.ERROR_MESSAGE_TIME_OUT,
        throwable
    ))
}
```

#### Issue

Note: we use `throwable -> new ..` inside parentheses, nothing more. The exception instance is just created (and returned implicitly), we do not throw it - we supply it to *vavr* which throws then.

You passed a *consumer* instead. The consuming lambda `{ throw new  ...; }` is throwing a new Exception immediately instead of simply mapping it with `{ return new CustomException("Custom message", thrown); }`.

#### See also

- [How to throw exception when Try.of() fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404926/how-to-throw-exception-when-try-of-fails)
- [TimeLimiter: Decorate and execute a functional interface](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/timeout#decorate-and-execute-a-functional-interface)
- Concept of `Try.of` applied to [CircuitBreaker: Decorate and execute a functional interface](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/circuitbreaker#decorate-and-execute-a-functional-interface)

### Exceptions from `TimeLimiter`

> throw the exception that the "methodWhichThrowsCustomException" throws

Assume you have a method:

```java
public String sayHelloWorld(boolean shouldThrow) throws CustomException {
    if (shouldThrow) throw new CustomException("Hello Exception");
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

You pass this to the `TimeLimiter`
When it executes and it was not able to complete successfully within time,
it throws either of two exceptions

1. when exceeding the time-limit, Resilience4J throws a `TimeoutException`:

> When a timeout occurs, it cancels the running Future before throwing a `TimeoutException`.

2. for any other `ExecutionException`, like when your method throws a custom exception, it will find that cause and rethrow this exception. See [`TimeLimiterImpl`, catch-block, line 57](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/d74e254fab7085322849282b2d924fbfbd3daed1/resilience4j-timelimiter/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/timelimiter/internal/TimeLimiterImpl.java#L57).

Then you should be able to catch it:

```java
try {
    // The blocking variant which is basically future.get(timeoutDuration, MILLISECONDS)
    String result = timeLimiter.executeFutureSupplier(
  () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sayHelloWorld(true)));
    log.info(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e); // or print to debug, handle, etc.
}
```

or using Vavr's [Try](https://docs.vavr.io/#_try):

```
String result = Try.of(() -> timeLimiter.executeFutureSupplier(
  () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> sayHelloWorld(true))) // method forced to throw
).getOrElseThrow(throwable -> throwable); // will throw as is (without mapping to another exception)
log.info(result);
```

See also:

[Implementing Timeouts with Resilience4j - Reflectoring](https://reflectoring.io/time-limiting-with-resilience4j/)